# Column edit as Combo Box in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I have got color data in a cell. It is possible that when i double click on this cell I can edit it only by selecting value from Combo Box ?

But this combobox is not visible all the time - only when i click double time.

**Questions:**

1. How to make that only one column is Editable (not all columns !)
2. When i double click on this column QTableWidget shows QComboBox with my value to insert in this cell. - how to do it ?

Comment: look at this [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-spinboxdelegate.html) with QSpinBox

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, using custom itemDelegates.

The way to success will be:

1. Subclass `QAbstractItemDelegate`, reimplement `createEditor` and make sure it creates combobox You love.
2. use `setItemDelegateForColumn` and specify a column with your color content.

Hint: you can even customize display of your color data, not only editing!

Now, let speak about setting only one column editable. You have a choice.

Way 1. Do it at model level. Let Your model returns proper flags in `flags(QModelIndex)` and make only Your column editable.

Way 2. View level. In this case You should create a "dumb" itemDelegate which does not create editor at all and assign it to all other columns.

Personally, I like way 1. But this is for You to choose.